How to set data() value in Vue before loading template
I tried multiple solutions for this problem.
I have two objects (user_1, user_2) that are loaded and set in App.vue like that
beforeCreate() {
    this.$store.dispatch("initializeUser");
    try {
      this.user_1 =  getUser("lukasz");
      this.user_2 =  getUser("karolina");
      this.$store.commit("setUser_1", this.user_1)
      this.$store.commit("setUser_2", this.user_2)

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching users:", error);
    }
  },

async function getUser(user) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/users/username/${user}`);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching user:", error);
    throw error; // Re-throw the error to be caught by the caller
  }
}

and after that template, StartPage is loading because !hasUser returns false at first
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <StartPage v-if="!hasUser" />  <div v-else>  <Navbar />
    <section class="section">
      <router-view />
    </section>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

but then in StartPage when I try to set user_1 and user_2 value from store to local variables everything works fine until router-link gives error that user_2 and user_1 are undefined even though I print them in mounted() function and there they are.
I tried using beforeMount(), created(), separating this function outside of export but it did not help either.
I know that if I hardcode some value in place of user_1 and user_2 site loads fine so there must be an issue
Here is StartPage.vue in which the error occurs
<template>
  <div>
    <router-link class="user2" :to="{name: 'User View', params: {user: this.user_2.username}}">
      <div class="split left" @mouseover="setHearts" @click="setSelectedUser(user_2)">
        <div class="centered">
          <button>{{ this.user_2.username }}</button>
        </div>
        <HeartIcon v-for="index in hearts" :key="index" class="heart"></HeartIcon>
      </div>
    </router-link>

    <router-link class="user1" :to="{name: 'User View', params: {user: this.user_1.username}}">
      <div class="split right" @mouseover="setFootballs" @click="setSelectedUser(user_1)">
        <div class="centered">
          <button class="button-text">{{ this.user_1.username }}</button>
        </div>
        <FootballIcon v-for="index in footballs" :key="index" class="football"></FootballIcon>
      </div>
    </router-link>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import HeartIcon from "@/components/Heart.vue";
import FootballIcon from "@/components/Football.vue";

export default {
  name: 'StartPage',
  computed: {},
  data() {
    return {
      hearts: 10,
      footballs: 10,
      user_1: {},
      user_2: {}
    }
  },
  components: {
    HeartIcon,
    FootballIcon
  },
  methods: {
    setHearts() {
      const hearts = document.querySelectorAll('.left .heart');
      hearts.forEach(heart => {
        const maxTop = window.innerHeight - heart.clientHeight; // Maximum top position
        const maxLeft = window.innerWidth - heart.clientWidth; // Maximum left position
        const randomTop = Math.random() * maxTop;
        const randomLeft = Math.random() * maxLeft;
        heart.style.top = `${randomTop}px`;
        heart.style.left = `${randomLeft}px`;
        heart.style.transform = `rotate(${Math.random() * 90 - 45}deg)`;
      });
    },

    setFootballs() {
      const footballs = document.querySelectorAll('.right .football');
      footballs.forEach(football => {
        const maxTop = window.innerHeight - football.clientHeight; // Maximum top position
        const maxLeft = window.innerWidth - football.clientWidth; // Maximum left position
        const randomTop = Math.random() * maxTop;
        const randomLeft = Math.random() * maxLeft;
        football.style.top = `${randomTop}px`;
        football.style.left = `${randomLeft}px`;
        football.style.transform = `rotate(${Math.random() * 90 - 45}deg)`;
      });
    },
    async setSelectedUser(user) {
      try {
        // Call an action to commit the selected user to the store
        await this.$store.dispatch("setSelectedUser", user);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error setting selected user:", error);
      }
    },
    setUsers() {
      this.user_1 = this.$store.state.user_1
      this.user_2 = this.$store.state.user_2
    }

  },
  mounted() {
    this.setUsers();
  }
}
</script>

And the error I am receiving
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function 
  at <RouterLink class="user2" to= {name: 'User View', params: {…}} > 
  at <StartPage key=0 > 
  at <App>

vue-router.mjs:1146 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Missing required param "user"

How can I solve this problem?

template code always runs on component creation.  you have to work around it.  you don't fetch user_1 or user_2's values from the store until the mounted hook.  unless the fetching is async it will probably just work if you change mounted() to created().  alternatively, a v-if will prevent rendering error until the users have values (are non-empty objects), e.g. <router-link v-if="Object.keys(user_1).length > 0".  ANOTHER alternative, pass the users down as props so the values are immediately available.

P.S. you don't need to use this in template code.
